# Cloudfront Automatically Switches File Content-Encoding

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket with a Javascript file that is updated with some Github actions, I noticed that whenever the file is uploaded, the Content-Encoding of the Javascript file is changed to Gzip thereby causing Cloudfront to always serve the Gzipped version of the file when requested from a browser even if the browser supports Brotli.

How can I fix it that whenever the file is uploaded through Github action, the content-encoding doesn't change and it retains only the `Content-Type: Application/javascript`?

If I upload the file directly using FTP like Cyberduck, everything works as expected. below is my current approach to uploading the file with Github action:

```
    - name: Deploy to production CDN and invalidate
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
      uses: lbertenasco/s3-deploy@v1
      with:
        folder: test
        bucket: ${{ secrets.S3_BUCKET }}
        dist-id: ${{ secrets.CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID }}
        invalidation: /example/example.js
```

Comment: Your chosen action does this without an option to change: https://github.com/lbertenasco/s3-deploy/blob/master/deploy.js#L12

Comment: It looks like running that command is basically all that action does, I would just do manually via `run` block in actions so you can specify the options you desire.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm Can you give me a sample block to execute with Github actions?

Comment: The command is in the linked file.